# Understanding escapable closure

Tags: swift

Can someone help me in comprehending escapable closure by going through the below example (the code flow)

```
 public static func newTask(request: URLRequest, completionHandler: @escaping (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void) {
    if !something.xyz {
        completionHandler(nil, nil, xyz("something.xyz should be called before calling something.newTask"))
        return

    readWriteDispatchQueue.async {
        makeRequest(request: request, completionHandler: completionHandler)
    }

}
```

Which is being used like this (snippet from test case)

```
something.newTask(request: userInfoRequest, completionHandler: {
                userInfoData, userInfoResponse, userInfoError in

                if userInfoError != nil {
                    failureMessage = "userInfo API error"
                    requestSemaphore.signal()
                    return
                }

                if userInfoResponse as? HTTPURLResponse != nil {
                    let userInfoHttpResponse = userInfoResponse as! HTTPURLResponse
                    if userInfoHttpResponse.statusCode != 200 {
                        failureMessage = "failed"
                    }
                    let idAfter = IdRefreshToken.getToken()
                    if idAfter == idBefore {
                        failureMessage = "failed"
                    }
                    requestSemaphore.signal()
                } else {
                    failureMessage = "failed"
                    requestSemaphore.signal()
                }
            })
```

Thanks in advance

Alsom What does `userInfoError in` means here?

**Update:** So I am curious to understand the flow, like what is called and when?

Say, In the above code snippet we reach

`something.newTask(request: userInfoRequest, completionHandler: {`

We pass, `userInfoRequest` and `completionHandler: {`.

Also, what is the typeof completionHandler above? In JS, we declare an object like this `completionHandler: {`

I am assuming that for `closure` this is how we pass function and then it processes the code. inside that completion handler.

My Understanding is We pass `completionHandler` to `static func newTask`.  `completionHandler` is just a function here which is used to emit event upwards to the calling function (`public static func newTask`) to execute after the  public static func newTask is processed ?

When we do `completionHandler(nil, nil, xyz("something.xyz should be called before calling something.newTask"))` we are passing `userInfoData, userInfoResponse, userInfoError` to completionHandler as `nil, nil xyz("something.xyz should be called before calling something.newTask")`

Not sure how much of this makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what is called and when?

First, `something.newTask` is called, so this block gets executed:

```
if !something.xyz {
    completionHandler(nil, nil, xyz("something.xyz should be called before calling something.newTask"))
    return
}
readWriteDispatchQueue.async {
    makeRequest(request: request, completionHandler: completionHandler)
}
```

If it goes into the `if` statement, then `completionHandler`, which in this case is everything inside the `{ ... }` you passed to `newTask` gets called with the specified parameters there.

Otherwise, `readWriteDispatchQueue.async` gets called, and `newTask` returns. A very short time after `newTask` returns (because this is "async"), `makeRequest` gets called and returns. After `makeRequest` finishes doing what it's doing (maybe when it has received a response?), `completionHandler` gets called.

> Also, what is the typeof completionHandler above?

It's type is written in the method signature `(Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void`, read as "a closure that takes a `Data?`, `URLResponse?` and `Error?` and returns nothing".

> I am assuming that for closure this is how we pass function and then it processes the code

Correct. In Swift, closures are denoted by `{ ... }`. For more info on the syntax of closures, read [the swift guide](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html).

> My Understanding is We pass completionHandler to static func newTask. completionHandler is just a function here which is used to emit event upwards to the calling function (public static func newTask) to execute after the public static func newTask is processed?

Though the wording is a bit non-standard. I think you got the idea.

> When we do completionHandler(nil, nil, xyz("something.xyz should be called before calling something.newTask")) we are passing userInfoData, userInfoResponse, userInfoError to completionHandler as nil, nil xyz("something.xyz should be called before calling something.newTask")

I would say that we are passing `nil, nil, xyz("something.xyz should be called before calling something.newTask")` *to* `completionHandler`, not the other way around.

Comment: Hey @Sweeper, You are awesome. This answer my question. Just another question (which might not be relevant to the above code). What does this line means `userInfoError in

                if userInfoError != nil {` like `in` the above syntax? thanks again

Comment: @anny123 Remember that closures are basically functions. `userInfoData, userInfoResponse, userInfoError` are the three parameters of the function. The word `in` just acts as a separator to separate the parameters and the body. It's a bit similar to `=>` in a javascript lambda.